# How to redirect home to home

Tags: html, css

Redirecting home from the Index.HTML; Basically if I click home then I should be able to return back to the index.html regardless if im on it. How do I make it where I redirect it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Parcle Games</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='styles.css'>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
    <div class="navbar">
        <img src="background.png" class="logo">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" data-after="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/Project.html" data-after="Projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/About.html" data-after="About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pages/Contact.html" data-after="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

A Blank screen displays with nothing.

Comment: Just do that <li><a href="/" data-after="Home">Home</a></li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change from `href="index.html"` to `href="/index.html"`. This means that you are targeting the root of the website.

When you are just using `"index.html"` the default behavior is just to append "index.html" to whatever route you are already on, meaning if you are on mywebsite.com/blog the result will be mywebsite.com/blog/index.html.

Also I see that you have two opening tags of the html tag. You can delete the second one to keep the language attribute.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).